# HTML keyboard shortcuts in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I switched from Textmate to Sublime in the past few months and have been busy trying to re-train my brain and fingers to use the new shortcut keys.

In Textmate, when editing an HTML documents, I could highlight text and do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to wrap the selected text in `<b></b>` tags or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to wrap in `<i></i>`...among various other commands/tags.

So, is there a way to do that in Sublime? I know I can type <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> to create an empty set of `<b></b>` tags, but I want to be able to wrap selected text in various tags.

Comment: If Sublime Text has a user forum or mailing list you're probably better off asking this question there.

Comment: I've had fairly decent success asking Sublime Text questions here and the responses tend to be faster then the Sublime forums. Always worth a try. :)

Comment: Btw you can type cltr+alt+. to close open tag.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Mac:**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

**Windows/Linux:**
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Then type which tag you want (`i`, `b`, etc.).

Comment: So it's the same as in TextMate then. Great :)

Comment: Didn't know about this in TextMate either...just always used the specific commands for bold and italic. This is obviously a bit more flexible. :)

Comment: I also didn't know about it in TextMate!

Comment: Hate to bump such an old answer, but it's still relevant in google searches - windows command is alt + shift + w

Comment: DON'T use ctrl+shift+w on windows - default in ST3 is close entire window (all tabs).  `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "close_window" },`

Comment: Don't use `[ctrl+shift+w]` in Linux too. It is mapped for closing the entire Window. Rather its `["alt+shift+w"]` `{ "keys": ["alt+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } },`.

If you want to over write it with `"ctrl+shift+w"`, then put that combination in > Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

Comment: LOL! Closed my whole window.

Comment: @RajaVarma On my linux machine, this keybind and this feature via the menu dont do anything at all.. works on my mac though. Any idea?

Comment: @KarthikT I am just guessing, that the behaviour might have been overwritten by any other plugin or the key binding is not there at all. The `Key Bindings - User` overrides the `Key Bindings - Default`, so a double check on this might help.

Comment: @RajaVarma yes, figured there might be something like that but would the menu still show the keybind in that case? the edit-> tag -> wrap shows this keybind

Comment: Is there a way to edit both tags at once without manually selecting with `ctrl`? Since when either is selected, both are highlighted.

Answer (score 22):

```
    { "keys": ["super+alt+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<strong>${0:$SELECTION}</strong>" } },
{ "keys": ["super+alt+i"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<em>${0:$SELECTION}</em>" } }
```

Above can be added to user key bindings file to have selection surrounded by strong tags upon pressing Cmd+Alt+b and by italic tags upon pressing Cmd+Alt+i (on Mac).

Source: https://gist.github.com/3436510

Comment: In Windows you would use something like `["ctrl+alt+b"]` or `["ctrl+alt+i"]` instead of `super+alt+`

@sridhar Thank you